# Python Regex capture only word not number, not hex and full filename from AutoIt Source code

Tags: python, regex

Currently I have some Autoit Source code to analyze, I want to use Python re module to capture the only word, not number, not hex, and the full filename, would you please advise a pattern to caputre it?

For example:
AutoIt source code:

```sh
#NoTrayIcon
FileInstall("ncwine.exe", @TempDir & "/ncwine.exe")
FileInstall("GPA_To_EELU.jar", @TempDir & "/GPA_To_EELU.jar")
Run(@TempDir & "/ncwine.exe")
Run(@TempDir & "/GPA_To_EELU.jar")
```

Regex:

```py
regex = re.compile(r'\b[^\d\W]+\b')
regex.findall(clean_text(script))

['NoTrayIcon',
 'FileInstall',
 'ncwine',
 'exe',
 'TempDir',
 'ncwine',
 'exe',
 'FileInstall',
 'GPA_To_EELU',
 'jar',
 'TempDir',
 'GPA_To_EELU',
 'jar',
 'Run',
 'TempDir',
 'ncwine',
 'exe',
 'Run']
```

It splited as each single token, this is what I expected:

```py
['NoTrayIcon',
'FileInstall',
'ncwine.exe',
'@TempDir',
'ncwine.exe',
'FileInstall',
'GPA_To_EELU.jar',
'@TempDir',
'GPA_To_EELU.jar',
'Run',
'@TempDir',
'ncwine.exe',
'Run',
'@TempDir',
'GPA_To_EELU.jar']
```

But in some complex source code, there's some hex value, such as: `0x12c`, with above regex pattern, it will capture also.

so come back to the question, how to capture: only word, not hex, not number, and full filename?

Comment: try this `(?:\b|\B)[a-zA-Z@._]+\b`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use

```
@?[^\W\d]+(?:\.[^\W\d]+)*
```

The pattern matches:

- `@?` Match optional `@`
- `[^\W\d]+` Match 1+ word characters except a digit
- `(?:\.[^\W\d]+)*` Optionally repeat matching a `.` and 1+ word characters except a digit

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/osl9Vr/1)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following regex:

```
\w+\.[a-z]*|@*\b[a-z@]+
```

with *i* (case insensitive) option.

Note that the first alternative captures file names and the
second - words and *@* chars).

In order to omit hex numbers (in the second alternative) I added *\b*.
But since *@* can occur also before a "word", I had to add *@** at the
beginning of this alternative.

For a working example see https://regex101.com/r/eI9l2Q/3

Comment: Thanks, so far this solution working well, but how to exclude those hex? such as "0x1000", "0x80" it will capture all the "x"